# Facebook pixel helper shows purchase event works but facebook events manager doesn't show it

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-pixel

Using `fbq('track', "Purchase",{ currency: 'USD', value: 59.99 });`
[facebook pixel helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-pixel-helper/fdgfkebogiimcoedlicjlajpkdmockpc?hl=en) shows 'Purchase' event works ok (green) but [facebook events manager](https://www.facebook.com/events_manager/pixel/activity) doesn't show it after a few hours.

What reasons could there be?

How much time does it take for the events manager to be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the reports are updated after 24 hours.

Comment: I am not seeing facebook pixel events from mobile in events manager, but I see them when I use desktop - was events manager not real time when you had your problem? I don't think it takes 24hrs to refresh anymore.